# How can i remove the middle line on the signature pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsignature

How to remove  the middle line from CANVAS (Signature panel) in the jSignature plugin ?

*I am using libs/jSignature.min.noconflict.js *

http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. i am used in noconflict.html file and it's work

```
// This is the part where jSignature is initialized.
var $sigdiv = $("#signature").jSignature(
{
    'UndoButton':true,
    'background-color': 'transparent',
     'decor-color': 'transparent',
})
```